# Multiple dynamic routes on same level OR multiple layouts in [...catch-all]

Tags: routes, svelte, sveltekit, dynamic-routing

I have several endpoints, each of which has a number of entries. For each of these endpoints I need a separate layout. My challenge here is that each entry of each endpoint must be directly accessible, without a path in between, always via example.com/[slug]

My first thought was to use multiple dynamic routes on the same level. In this example for three endpoints:

```
src/
├ routes/
│ ├ [services]
│ │ └ +page.server.js
│ │ └ +page.svelte
│ ├ [solutions]
│ │ └ +page.server.js
│ │ └ +page.svelte
│ ├ [customers]
│ │ └ +page.server.js
│ │ └ +page.svelte
```

However, I have learned that this is not possible in Sveltekit and I could not find a suitable routing concept in the documentation.

How can I implement my use case with Sveltekit?

Is it perhaps possible to assign a separate layout to each endpoint within a [...catchall]?

Comment: I honestly haven't seen this in practice anywhere, even YouTube uses `channel/id` or `/videoid` for routing. SvelteKit is a filesystem-based router and `/` is the root route - `slug` can only be placed under a route, e.g. `/services/[id]`.  Perhaps I don't understand what you're trying to achieve; do see https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/routing. Maybe you could see how to get custom responses to specific events via hooks; https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/hooks